# How can I know the places is nearer ? (Android )

Tags: android, google-maps, latitude-longitude, geofire

How can I know two of the place near or not through their latitude and longitude getting from google map api ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get near places from lat-lng values..you can subtract them to see which one is nearer..
But I think you are looking for is geofire - which can track any object's location to tell you if that object is in the territory of the Desired location.
Go through [GeoFire](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/08/geofire-goes-mobile.html)

But if you want to only subtract the values of lat-lng then that is another case..The values of lat-lng you can get from [Google maps Api](https://developers.google.com/maps/)

Comment: I am studying how to know whether two passenger's destination is nearer and suggest them to share the ride. One of the passenger's destinations lat-lng value has been stored in the database. I am thinking a way to know their ride is on the same road or not.